# flutter firebase realtime database listen on value change save new and same value many times

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

i am  listening on value of  string  change to save it to local database .. it triggers saving the data many times .. for the same value .. is there's any way to make it  loop once on change ...

```
 locationListener() async {
   emit(LoadingListentLocState());
   String? latLong;
   final loc = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('h/location');

   emit(LoadingListentLocState());

   loc.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {

   latLong = event.snapshot.value.toString();

   CacheHelper.saveData(key: "latLong", value: latLong);
   locationsState = true;
   locationUpdated = true;
   getMapStatus = true;
   mapsStateMsg = MapStatesMsg(MapStates.LASTUPDATED);
   loadingWebViewMap(latLong);

    savingLocationToDB(latLong);

   emit(UpdatedListentLocState());
 });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could be looking for "**distinct**":

```
late StreamSubscription sub;
Stream<DatabaseEvent> stream = newClientRef.onValue;
sub = stream.distinct().listen(
(DatabaseEvent event) async {.. save ..}
```

[Distinct Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o96nD.png)